# DNS Service not running on a Sandboxed and alienated single Domain controller

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller

we were trying to created a sandboxed test environment; so we promoted a member server to a domain controller and then shut it down moved it to a sandboxed netwrok and cleaned up metadata. Everything was fine untill then but later when we tried to add a workstation to the domain in the sandbox, it failed because DNS lookup failed; Please do advice me how to recover from this? We cant move that DC to live domain again.

Please do let me know of any aditional questions.

Comment: Is the DC using itself for DNS? Does it have a copy of the AD DNS zone? Is it authoritative for the AD DNS zone? Are the correct DNS records for the DC registered in the DNS zone? Is the workstation using the DC for DNS? Do the DC and the workstation have layer 2 and layer 3 connectivity between them?

Comment: The DC should use itself for DNS since its the only DC in sandbox; It doesnt have copy of AD DNS zone; all it has is replicated ntds dit and sysvol and it is itself a domaincontroller.

Comment: That's what I'm implying, that the DC should use itself for DNS, assuming that the DNS role is also installed on the DC. Additionally, if the DC doesn't have a copy of the AD DNS zone then the workstation isn't going to be able to find the DNS SRV records for the DC in order to communicate with the DC and join the domain. Furthermore, the DC isn't going to function properly if it doesn't hold a copy of the AD DNS zone. Basically, you have no DNS support for the domain in the sandbox. My suggestion would be to start from scratch and follow the advice from MDMarra in his answer.

Comment: I actually just installed the DNS role on the DC and then created a forward zone  with domain name; it has host A for the server and Name server and a SOA; is it possoble to just create an SRV to make the workstation find the DC and get added to the domain? there wont be another DC in this sandbox, it will only be 1 DC and 1 Workstation.How can i create the SRV record manually for tricking the workstation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it; just exported the DNS zone from our domain using  "DNSCMD /ZONEEXPORT"  and then imported the whole thing in the sandbox using "DNSCMD /ZONEADD" command. Currently i was able to add my workstation to the domain.

Answer (score 3):

This really is not the right way to do what you want to do. If you want to populate a DC with a bunch of accounts to test with, you should promote the DC to a fresh test domain from a fresh OS install. Don't join it to the existing domain and move it. Then you can use a tool like `ldifde.exe` to export all of the accounts from your existing domain into the test one.

Comment: I don't know if I'd agree with that. There have been multiple migration test scenarios that I've mocked-up using virtual DCs that, initially, started their lives as replicas of a production domain. I think this is a perfectly valid technique, provided you understand how to get the "under glass" copy of the DC working properly and, of course, you understand that it can never be connected to the production network.

Comment: @Evan yes, my only fault was not obtaining the DNS stuff(which is not stored in AD in our domain); so i had to export the whole DNS zone seperately and import it in the sandbox DC and then spoofed one of the DC's ip addreses(In SRV records)  with Sandbox DC IP.